# A rogue process heats up my Mac - how to find and remove this program?

Tags: macbook-pro, software, activity-monitor

A year ago I got a used [Mindstorms EV3 set](https://www.ev3dev.org/), fired it up and played around with my son. I installed a setup where we could write Python scripts to control the robot. The connection to the robot used bluetooth. But it was too time consuming; so we stopped using it.

I think I uninstalled the parts that I could, but lately some EV3 manager part (Lego Mindstorms EV3 manager) has started running itself in the background erroneously, consuming 90% of CPU and heating up the computer. I can stop the process from Activity Monitor. But I struggle to find and remove this program. I have no clue why it fires up randomly!

Any help? If I see a process in Activity Monitor, is it possible to track down the program and remove it?

EDIT:

As suggested on this site, I sampled the rogue process in Activity Monitor to find its Path. The Path is

```
/Library/EV3 Device Manager/EV3DeviceManager
```

But navigating to Library I cannot see a folder named EV3 Device Manager at all. I believe I have deleted it in effort to stop this very problem. Also, as suggested here, I emptied trash bin and restarted my Mac. After a while, the rogue process still persists and launches itself maybe once a day.

I also did a search with Finder's search function for any files with EV3 in the name and only found my own written notes about this problem and nothing else.

Any suggestions on what to do next to hunt down and remove this erroneous program?

Comment: Sorry to hear the problem goes on. It might be worth trying the following if you haven't done it before: reinstall the Mindstorms EV3 software and delete it using its own uninstaller this time. If that doesn't work, you can also try an uninstaller such as [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) after reinstalling the software once more! Not sure how much it would help but upgrading to Ventura might be worth a try as well if that is something you are considering in any case. On another note, pls note that cross-posting the same question to multiple Stack Exchange sites is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

You can learn more about a process shown by Activity Monitor by double-clicking on it or clicking the Info ⓘ button at the top of the Activity Monitor window. The Open Files and Ports tab in the window to come out (the Info window) may especially help you find out which file may be associated with the process.

If that is not enough, click on the Sample button at the bottom of the Info window to launch a Sample window. At the top text in the Sample window, there should be a line beginning with `Path` that can help you further in figuring out the file associated with the process.

Here is a screenshot of the windows mentioned above, for example, for the process Microsoft Excel:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Now I caught the Sample of the process, and see the path
Path:            /Library/EV3 Device Manager/EV3DeviceManager

But when I navigate to the Library folder, it does not contain a folder named EV3 Device Manager. It is possible that I already deleted it in effort to kill this process that keeps appearing and eating all my CPU capacity. Any ideas for the next step in this hunt?

Comment: To add to the previous comments, when the process was running and I was inspecting it in Activity Monitor, the Info window did not contain the tab Open Files and Ports at all.

Comment: I haven't encountered a situation like this before but the file(s) should still be somewhere on your Mac. Have you emptied the Mac's trash after deleting the EV3 files? If the trash is emptied, press Option+Command+Space (to launch the Finder) and type `name:EV3` to search "This Mac" for any file or folder whose name includes `EV3` on your Mac and see if there is anything else to delete. If neither of these work, I suggest updating your original post with the additional information you got on the runaway process from the Info and Sample windows and also include the screenshots of the windows.

Comment: The trash bin had tons of files, emptied them. Will see if the rogue process still keeps appearing and if it does, will do as you suggested.

Comment: Better if you also restart your Mac after emptying trash.